# Too many values to unpack (expected 2) error when trying to get the values of more than one directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to access 2 directories simultaneously and have to work with the files like- if I work with 1st file from 1st directory then I have to work with 1st file from 2nd directory and so on. But when I  The code is:

```
for n, id_ in tqdm(enumerate(train_ids), total=len(train_ids)):
    path = TRAIN_PATH +'\\'+ id_
    path_image = path + '\\images\\'
    path_mask = path + '\\masks\\'
    for image_file, mask_file in os.listdir(path_image), os.listdir(path_mask):
        print(path_image+image_file)
        print(path_mask+mask_file)

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-b54928a597d2> in <module>
      3     path_image = path + '\\images\\'
      4     path_mask = path + '\\masks\\'
----> 5     for image_file, mask_file in os.listdir(path_image), os.listdir(path_mask):
      6         print(path_image+image_file)
      7         print(path_mask+mask_file)

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Could you paste the full error code?

Comment: @keiv.fly forgot to add error code. thnx mate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `zip` function for this type of problem

change

```py
for image_file, mask_file in os.listdir(path_image), os.listdir(path_mask):
```

into:

```py
for image_file, mask_file in zip(os.listdir(path_image), os.listdir(path_mask)):
```

## Explanation:

`zip` takes two iterables (or more) and make them as one:

lets say we have list `l` and `k`

```py
k = [1,2,3]
l = [4,5,6]
zip(l, k) # [(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]
```

Comment: but it changes the ordering of files and i don't want that

Comment: @Nemesis what do you mean? what order get chang?

Comment: i have sorted the files according to date-modified but it took according to name

Comment: @Nemesis you can extract `os.listdir(path_image)` into varible, modifie it, and just then put it inside the `zip` file

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, you want to iterate over two iterables at the same time (`os.listdir(path_image)` and `os.listdir(path_mask)`).

You cannot unpack two list-like objects in the same `for` expression. But you can achieve this by using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).

```
for image_file, mask_file in zip(os.listdir(path_image), os.listdir(path_mask)):
   ...
```

`zip` allows you to iterate at the same time over two (or more) iterables like lists.

Answer (score -2):

your "for-loop" approach is incorrect. See my example below.

You cannot unpack 2 lists into two variables due to the face - their lengths can be different and then python would not know how to handle the "for-statement"...

```
    a = [1, 2, 3]
    b = [4, 5, 6]

    for z, x in a, b:
        print(z)
        print(x)
```

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

You need to make one iterateable object

use @Reznik offer, it'd do the work.